# Electron - textarea not reacting to change events

Tags: javascript, electron

I have following code in my electron app. First I initialize it with:

```js
app.on('ready', createWindow);

function createWindow() {
  window.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'technical/views/highlightRules.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }));
}
```

My highlightRules.html has the following in it

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../ioadapters/controllers/HighlightRulesController.js"></script>

...

<textarea id="lowValueSettingText" rows="8"></textarea>
```

And lastly HighlightRulesController.js has the following:

```js
function setUp() {
  const lowValueSettingTextarea = document.getElementById("lowValueSettingText");

  lowValueSettingTextarea.onchange = function() {
    onLowValueHighlightSettingChanged();
  }
}

function onLowValueHighlightSettingChanged() {
  alert("test");
}

setUp();
```

When I type something into the textarea and it loses focus no alert is being shown. I expect the onLowValueHighlightSettingChanged function to be executed.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Where does `setUp()` get called?

Comment: It gets called below the method definitions. Edited the question to include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. I put the  tag in highlightRules.html into the head area.

Once I moved it to the bottom of body it started working.

Correct place to put the script tag:

```html
<body>
  ...

  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../ioadapters/controllers/HighlightRulesController.js"></script>
</body>
```